# Infer type from one part of object parameter to the other

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I have a function that takes in an object parameter. Depending what I put in one part of the object I want to infer those types for use in another part of the object.

I have it working, but the object isn't formatted exactly as I like.

```js
// This code is working

type Getter<State, S extends Setter<State>> = {
    [K in keyof State]: (v: State[K]) => Parameters<S[K]>[0];
};
type Setter<State> = {
    [K in keyof State]: (v: any) => State[K];
};
interface Opts<State, X extends Setter<State>> {
    state: State;
    getter: Getter<State, X>;
    setter: X;
}

function create<State, X extends Setter<State>>(opts: Opts<State, X>) {
    // Implementation doesn't matter right now
    return opts;
}

create({
    state: {
        s1: 5,
        s2: '9',
    },
    getter: {
        s1: n => n.toString(), // This is typed at `(n: number) => string;`, inferred from `state` and `setter`.
        s2: s => parseInt(s, 10), // This is typed at `(s: string) => number;`, inferred from `state` and `setter`.
    },
    setter: {
        s1: (s: string) => parseInt(s, 10),
        s2: (n: number) => n.toString(),
    },
});
```

What I would like the implementation to look like below but I can't seem to get the types to work out.

```js
create({
    state: {
        s1: 5,
        s2: '9',
    },
    gettersAndSetters: {
        s1: {
            get: n => n.toString(), // Should be `(n: number) => string` inferred from `state` and the `set` function parameter.
            set: (s: string) => parseInt(s, 10),
        },
        s2: {
            get: s => parseInt(s, 10), // Should be `(s: string) => number` inferred from `state` and the `set` function parameter.
            set: s2: (n: number) => n.toString(),
        }
    },
});
```

**EDIT**

I'd like the following code to throw errors.

Basically the state part should dictate the first parameter of the `get` method and the return type of the `set` method.
The first parameter of the `set` method should dictate the first parameter of the `get` method.

```js
create({
    state: {
        s1: 5,
    },
    gettersAndSetters: {
        s1: {
            get: n => {
              // This should throw an error because `n` should be typed as number.
              parseInt(n, 10);
              // The return should throw an error because it should be typed as returning a string, not a number.
              return 5;
            }
            set: (s: string) => {
              // The return should throw an error because it should be typed as returning a number, not a string.
              return 'mystring';
            },
        },
    },
});
```

I understand that this may not be possible with typescript. I did get it to work if I split the getters and setters up into their own objects (see my original code at the top), but I cannot not get it to work with keys having the get and set methods.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/N52qom) work for your use cases?  If so, I'll write up an answer; if not, please [edit] your code to demonstrate failing use cases.  Note that it's notoriously tricky in TS to get both generic type parameter inference and contextual callback parameter inference happening from the same object at the same time, so unless you're willing to refactor into something better for the compiler (such as your original version) you might not find something that works for all reasonable use cases.  Let me know.

Comment: It doesn't seem to quite work. It's not enforcing the return type of the get method. It does enforce the `get` parameter, but not the `get` return type. I've updated the question to show a bit more of the use cases. I know this is a particular tricky thing to do in Typescript. I'd be open to alternative approaches, even in refactoring how I'm doing it.

Comment: Okay, does [this work better](https://tsplay.dev/N7ga4N) for you?  Please test it out since there are plenty of potential pitfalls.  By the way, if you're open to refactoring how you're doing it, what's wrong with your original solution?

Comment: It doesn't seem to cause an error on the `return 5` (line 55). It seems to be really close, but the `U[K]` in the `Opts` interface is being typed as `any` and not being inferred from the `set` method. True, I guess I'm just being pedantic. I like the shape of the second way better than my original and I also love to see if I can push Typescript further and see what's possible.

Comment: I'm not really sure what to say about exactly where the error appears; if you give it something inconsistent, it's really up to the compiler to decide where to complain.  In this case it fails to infer and some types fall back to `any`.  If you can show a use case where there's an error for a call which shouldn't have one, or vice versa, then I'd be more inclined to try to change things.  As it stands, it looks like you just don't like the location of the errors, and I don't really have magic knobs to turn to fix that.  If you want to see the current version as an answer, let me know.

Comment: I'm not sure you quite understood my reasoning with the errors, but that's ok. I think my conclusion is this is not answerable without changing it. I'm actually pretty amazed at how close Typescript got, but I guess inferring and dictating types to the same part isn't that possible. Makes sense I guess.